# find maximum don't work with me i don' know why?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, parameters

i have  log function like this and i want to find maximum for it
the log function like this

```
{Log[0.0084601458 (1 - 0.8559631 \[Gamma])] + Log[0.065487496 (1 - 0.3055464 \[Gamma])] + Log[0.121124519 (1 - 0.1789699 \[Gamma])] +  Log[0.173268258 (1 - 0.0309691 \[Gamma])] +  Log[0.220542089 (1 + 0.1796384 \[Gamma])] +   Log[0.0161033550 (1 + 0.538130 \[Gamma])], Log[0.000236977868 (1 - 0.9846286 \[Gamma])] +  Log[0.117328029 (1 - 0.4572826 \[Gamma])] + Log[0.160633344 (1 + 0.0306330 \[Gamma])] +   Log[0.154649355 (1 + 0.1365083 \[Gamma])] + Log[0.0334784363 (1 + 0.4679368 \[Gamma])] +  Log[0.00259914489 (1 + 0.8001751 \[Gamma])]}
```

i used find maximum like this

```
mle = FindMaximum[{Log[
 0.0084601457831837076814994363384560592`8.785596449099556 (1 - 
    0.8559630660472515274`7.216194637933361 \[Gamma])] + 
    Log[0.06548749562384812167095352160773052768`8.766007072157514 (1 \
- 0.3055463851851426448`7.025589313375022 \[Gamma])] + 
    Log[0.12112451949682492366273182081801936726`8.742188618150676 (1 \
- 0.1789699290453014345`7.134296059083023 \[Gamma])] + 
    Log[0.17326825805506991355920749084220183399`8.755689959161463 (1 \
- 0.0309691359518648795`6.234870125904975 \[Gamma])] + 
    Log[0.22054208923097404085790774267703114375`8.756602690942103 (1 \
+ 0.1796383933009105987`7.036447828876202 \[Gamma])] + 
    Log[0.01610335498101282196561022522139224541`8.841030000038854 (1 \
+ 0.5381300860978949101`6.69241919410516 \[Gamma])], 
   Log[0.00023697786836160285728076406727348666`8.649414633060987 (1 \
- 0.9846285695834126921`7.680070381812083 \[Gamma])] + 
    Log[0.11732802945784683638832707265801352311`8.780148043628628 (1 \
- 0.4572825739452851325`7.522024930822745 \[Gamma])] + 
    Log[0.16063334426377101686809044186175635345`8.813798796432467 (1 \
+ 0.0306329510642554364`5.999123664538637 \[Gamma])] + 
    Log[0.15464935530717175197280826252245813324`8.819257288358918 (1 \
+ 0.1365083459770376563`6.592564013012948 \[Gamma])] + 
    Log[0.03347843631363023577524420927276156891`8.840674292618228 (1 \
+ 0.4679368465726207553`6.908911523620153 \[Gamma])] + 
    Log[0.00259914488700714435319841865751134831`8.825318482176566 (1 \
+ 0.8001750561580153903`6.9677546267445205 \[Gamma])]}, {-1 < \
\[Gamma] < 1}, {\[Gamma], .1}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```

but the result as follows

[image: res]

Comment: You've got `FindMaximum[{func1, func2, constraint}, {..}, opt]` — looks like an extra comma. Or if you're trying to maximize two scalar functions at once or one vector-valued function, it can't be done. You could maximize the norm of a vector, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr1 = {Log[0.0084601458 (1 - 0.8559631 γ)] + 
    Log[0.065487496 (1 - 0.3055464 γ)] + 
    Log[0.121124519 (1 - 0.1789699 γ)] + 
    Log[0.173268258 (1 - 0.0309691 γ)] + 
    Log[0.220542089 (1 + 0.1796384 γ)] + 
    Log[0.0161033550 (1 + 0.538130 γ)], 
   Log[0.000236977868 (1 - 0.9846286 γ)] + 
    Log[0.117328029 (1 - 0.4572826 γ)] + 
    Log[0.160633344 (1 + 0.0306330 γ)] + 
    Log[0.154649355 (1 + 0.1365083 γ)] + 
    Log[0.0334784363 (1 + 0.4679368 γ)] + 
    Log[0.00259914489 (1 + 0.8001751 γ)]};

Maximize[{#, -1 < γ < 1}, γ] & /@ expr1

(* {{-16.8031, {γ -> -0.618032}}, {-23.535, {γ -> -0.00323828}}} *)
```

For better precision

```
expr2 = expr1 // Rationalize[#, 0] & // FullSimplify;

N[Maximize[{#, -1 < γ < 1}, γ] & /@ expr2]

(* {{-16.8031, {γ -> -0.618033}}, {-23.535, {γ -> -0.00323828}}} *)
```